# No rows are selected if table in join doesn't have row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a query to select information about all the questions on a quiz (`ModuleId`). I need the most recent user answer, along with the question, the answer key, and the grader information, if there is any.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetQuestionsAnswersMostRecentUserAnswersAndRevisions
    (@UserId char(7), @ModuleId int) 
AS
    SELECT 
        ua.QuestionId, ua.UserAnswerId, UserAnswer, Question, Answer, 
        TypeId, GraderRevision, IsAnswerCorrect 
    FROM 
        UserAnswersByModule ua
    INNER JOIN 
        QuestionsAnswersByModule qa ON qa.QuestionId = ua.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN 
        GradedAnswersByQuestion ga ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
    WHERE 
        ua.UserAnswerId IN (SELECT MAX(UserAnswerId) AS MostRecentUserAnswer 
                            FROM UserAnswersByModule 
                            WHERE ModuleId = @ModuleId 
                              AND UserId = @UserId 
                              AND IsActive = 1 
                            GROUP BY QuestionId)
        AND ga.RevisionId IN (SELECT MAX(RevisionId) AS MostRecentRevisionId 
                              FROM GradedAnswersByQuestion GA
                              INNER JOIN UserAnswersByModule ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
                              WHERE UserId = @UserId
                                AND ModuleId = @ModuleId
                              GROUP BY GA.UserAnswerId)
```

This is how the tables are set up:

**QuestionAnswersByModule**:

```
PK - QuestionId
```

**UserAnswersByModule**:

```
PK - UserAnswerId
FK - QuestionAnswersByModule.QuestionId
```

**GradedAnswersByQuestion**:

```
PK - RevisionId
FK - UserAnswersByModule.UserAnswerId
```

The problem with my query is that, if there isn't anything in `GradedAnswersByQuestion` for the particular `UserAnswerId`, the query returns nothing at all, instead of null for those two columns and the rest of the information. I'm pretty sure it's because of the `AND ga.RevisionId IN ...` but I can't think of how else to write it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this does the trick with minimal changes...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetQuestionsAnswersMostRecentUserAnswersAndRevisions(@UserId char(7),@ModuleId int) AS
SELECT ua.QuestionId, ua.UserAnswerId, UserAnswer, Question, Answer, TypeId, GraderRevision, IsAnswerCorrect 
FROM UserAnswersByModule ua
INNER JOIN QuestionsAnswersByModule qa
ON qa.QuestionId = ua.QuestionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN GradedAnswersByQuestion ga /* <-- Changed! */
ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
WHERE ua.UserAnswerId 
IN (
  SELECT MAX(UserAnswerId) AS MostRecentUserAnswer FROM UserAnswersByModule WHERE ModuleId = @ModuleId AND UserId = @UserId AND IsActive = 1 GROUP BY QuestionId
)
AND (
  ga.RevisionId is null /* <-- Changed! */
  OR ga.RevisionId IN (
    SELECT MAX(RevisionId) AS MostRecentRevisionId 
    FROM GradedAnswersByQuestion GA
    INNER JOIN UserAnswersByModule
    ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
    AND ModuleId = @ModuleId
    GROUP BY GA.UserAnswerId
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried your version and I am still getting the same results.  When I run the query with empty rows in the graded table it returns nothing.  I wanted to note I have tried left joins but wasn't able to get any further.

Edit - Actually I missed one of the changes you made, let me try it again and I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Ok. Great I was going to offer a different version but I guess that won't be necessary!

Answer (score 1):

An inner join by definition returns rows that are contained in both tables that are being joined.  Take a look at left and right joins and see if they fit your intended goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetQuestionsAnswersMostRecentUserAnswersAndRevisions
(
    @UserId char(7),
    @ModuleId int
) AS
SELECT
    ua.QuestionId, ua.UserAnswerId,
    UserAnswer, Question, Answer, TypeId, GraderRevision, IsAnswerCorrect 
FROM
    UserAnswersByModule ua
    INNER JOIN QuestionsAnswersByModule qa
        ON qa.QuestionId = ua.QuestionId
    INNER JOIN GradedAnswersByQuestion ga
        ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(RevisionId) AS MostRecentRevisionId 
        FROM GradedAnswersByQuestion GA
        GROUP BY GA.UserAnswerId
    ) AS mr_ga
        ON mr_ga.RevisionId = ga.RevisionId
WHERE
    UserId = @UserId AND ModuleId = @ModuleId
    AND ua.UserAnswerId IN (
        SELECT MAX(UserAnswerId) AS MostRecentUserAnswer
        FROM UserAnswersByModule
        WHERE ModuleId = ua.ModuleId AND UserId = ua.UserId AND IsActive = 1
        GROUP BY QuestionId
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a left join and apply  filter condition on that .

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE        
   spGetQuestionsAnswersMostRecentUserAnswersAndRevisions(@UserId char(7),@ModuleId int) AS
SELECT ua.QuestionId, ua.UserAnswerId, UserAnswer, Question, Answer, TypeId, GraderRevision,      IsAnswerCorrect 
   FROM UserAnswersByModule ua
   INNER JOIN QuestionsAnswersByModule qa
       ON qa.QuestionId = ua.QuestionId
  LEFT JOIN GradedAnswersByQuestion ga
        ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId 
           AND      ga.RevisionId IN (
          SELECT 
   MAX(RevisionId) AS     MostRecentRevisionId 
   FROM GradedAnswersByQuestion GA
     INNER JOIN UserAnswersByModule
        ON ga.UserAnswerId = ua.UserAnswerId
      WHERE UserId = @UserId
         AND ModuleId = @ModuleId
   GROUP BY GA.UserAnswerId
    )
 Where ua.UserAnswerId IN (
    SELECT MAX(UserAnswerId) AS     MostRecentUserAnswer 
     FROM UserAnswersByModule 
      WHERE ModuleId = @ModuleId 
      AND UserId =     @UserId 
     AND IsActive = 1 GROUP BY QuestionId
     )
```